# What is the "internal language of a topos"?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

What does the sentence "[...] these statements should be interpreted, of course, in the internal language of the topos $\mathcal{E}$" mean, in the context of, say, the definition of a groupoid in $\mathcal{E}$ as a graph satisfying equations and endowed with an associative composition?

I am only familiar with Grothendieck topoi. Does that statement have something to do with the logic aspects of elementary topoi?

Comment: Yes. Of course, Grothendieck toposes are elementary toposes too.

Comment: See [the nLab entry on the internal language of a topos](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Mitchell-B%C3%A9nabou+language) for a first start. Textbook references are listed at the bottom of [this article](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+logic). Extremely briefly, the internal language is a device which gives you the following dictionary: object of $\mathcal{E}$ = "set" [really: type], morphism in $\mathcal{E}$ = "map of sets", epimorphism in $\mathcal{E}$ = surjective map, monomorphism in $\mathcal{E}$ = injective map, subobject classifier in $\mathcal{E}$ = powerset of $\{\heartsuit\}$, ...